# Cannot delete an entire google spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

So i want to to create a python script which will delete an entire google spreadsheet. I am using a google service account to actually create new spreadsheets, pass and delete data and interact with google API through python. The following code is supposed to be deleting a specific spreadsheet according to the its id. When i run it i get 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file' error. Tried setting owner permissions for the service account from google, but it did't work either. What am i doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import sys

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]


ID = mysheet_id
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='client_secret.json')

gc.del_spreadsheet(ID)

print(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the scopes you are trying to add to your service account, for example, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` are part of **Restricted** scopes, and such Google has stricter requirements for verification as per document.

Referring to [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth):

> **Restricted** - These scopes provide wide access to Google User Data and  require you to go through a restricted scope verification
> process. For  information on this requirement, see Google API
> Services: User Data  Policy and Additional Requirements for Specific
> API Scopes. If you store  restricted scope data on servers (or
> transmit), then you need to go through a security assessment.

Comment: Hello! I replaced those scopes with the recommended ones , but still no luck..